# User relationship ignored in autocomplete entity reference view

Tags: entities, views, ajax

I have a content type called "games". I also have a rol for users named "players" and another "trainer". Each player and trainer has a "team" also. This is very simple: when the user (a trainer) adds a new Match he has an entity reference view autocomplete to add the players.

So far, so good. Now i 've just added a relationship in the entity reference view selecting the team of the user (he would be the trainer) in order to get the listing only with the players of the same team.
In this way, the trainer only can add those players of his team.

My problem is the autocomplete totally ignores this relationship showing any player of any team. :(

Comment: Not quite - ER doesn't claim to do any sort of automatic contextual filtering, so it's not ignoring anything - it's just behaving as you've configured it to behave so far. To get advanced (i.e. beyond entity bundle) conditions into it, you need to create an Entity Reference Widget view, get that contextually filtering as fits your use case, and then use that instead of the basic option on the field config

Comment: sir, only views with a display of type "Entity Reference" are eligible.
in the autocomplete field, at Entity Selection  i don't see how to use an Entity Reference Widget View :(

Comment: It's a display type - so add a new view, and then add a new display to it; you'll see the option for an entity reference view